# .htaccess Rewrite Query String

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have troubles redirecting query strings and I really can't find a way how to do it. Let me be more specific:
I want to achieve the following: Redirect `http://blablabla.com/default.asp?Kategori=1&Valg=77` to: `http://blablabla.com/default_Kategori_1_Valg_77.html`

Any help will be very appreciated.
Kind Regards,
Pavel Nikolaev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Kategori=1&Valg=77$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^default\.asp$ http://blablabla.com/default_Kategori_1_Valg_77.html? [L,R]
```

Comment: Works smoothly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide a new version of what starkeen advised me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Kategori=(.*)&Valg=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^default\.asp$ http://blablabla.com/default_Kategori_%1_Valg_%2.html? [L,R]
```

The difference is that know I am catching the values of the Kategori and Valg parameters and use them in the new URL. Really interesting!
Thank you all.